# How to correctly fill and send a dynamic array to a function in c ++ from Delphi

Tags: c++, arrays, delphi

I have the following c++ function:

```
    public:
__int32 __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall finalizeModelling(
            __int32 model,
            float   * vertices,
            __int32 * indices,
            __int32 FVF
        );
```

vertices and indices varibles are arrays.

In delphi I have:

```
TFinalizeModelling    = 
function  (AModel : NativeInt; var AVertices : array of TFloat; var AIndices : array of Integer; AFVF : NativeInt) : NativeInt; stdcall;
```

I try to use:

```
  TFloat = Single;
  PVerticesArray = ^TPVerticesArray;
  TPVerticesArray  = array of TFloat;

  PIndicesArray = ^TPIndicesArray;
  TPIndicesArray  = array of Integer;
```

and

```
TFinalizeModelling    = 
function  (AModel : NativeInt; var AVertices : PVerticesArray ; var AIndices : PIndicesArray ; AFVF : NativeInt) : NativeInt; stdcall;
```

I have declare two variables:

```
  vArray: PVerticesArray;
  indices: PIndicesArray;
```

and I make a function call like:

```
  EngineDll.FinalizeModelling(FModel, vArray, indices, 0);
```

but I get an access violation.

My question is:
What is the correct way to declare and SetLength a dynamic array to be used with the function in C ++?

The function will be called several times with different array lengths and different content.

Comment: Every single parameter is declared incorrectly. C++ int maps to Integer in Delphi, and presumably __int32 expands to int. As for the arrays, declare them as pointers and pass the address of the first element of your delphi arrays. Finally, that doesn't look like a static method. Is it an instance method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your declaration is incorrect.

The `NativeInt` declaration is wrong. Use `Int32` or `Integer`.

The declaration of the arrays can *never* be an open array (your first declaration) nor a dynamic array (your "answer"). Note that open array parameters and dynamic arrays only *look* similar, they are not. (*cf. [Open array parameters and array of const — Confusion](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html#confusion)*)

The original declaration uses pointers, so use pointers too. Your arrays can be static or dynamic, but the **parameter declarations** can never be.

So make it:

```
type
  TFinalizeModelling = 
    function(AModel: Int32; 
      AVertices: PSingle; // PSingle = ^Single, declare the type if necessary
      AIndices: PInteger; // PInteger = ^Integer 
      AFVF: Int32): Int32; stdcall;
```

Now you can do what you wanted, but be sure to pass **pointers** to the first elements of your arrays:

```
Blah := FinalizeModelling(YourModel, @YourVertices[0], @YourIndices[0], 0);
```

Where `YourVertices` and `YourIndices` can be static or dynamic arrays.

---

*Dynamic arrays are Delphi-specific types. They should never be passed across a DLL boundary. The original C++ declaration doesn't do this, but your translation does. Your "solution" very likely "works", but can cause problems with reference counting.*

*Also note that dynamic array variables are already pointers (reference types). **Never** translate a C++ pointer as a dynamic array, and most definitely not as a **pointer to a dynamic array**.*

*More info: [Pitfalls of converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html).*

Comment: This is odd. You don't need pointermath. You declare the arrays as pointers and pass the address of the first element of the array. In the Delphi code you access elements using array syntax. Typically these would be dynamic arrays. Pass the address of the first element and let the code on the other side of the interface do its thing.

Comment: Whether they **are** dynamic arrays or not is irrelevant, if the user allocates them. You can indeed pass the first element. But the *declaration* as dynamic array of the parameter type is wrong, and especially as a pointer to one. But you are right, this can be simplified. I'll rewrite.

Comment: I agree with all of that. Just not the statement that pointer math is needed. There's also really nothing to be said for declaring array types of some arbitrary large size. We've had dynamic arrays for years now. Please stop propagating that nonsense.

Comment: Right, that's much better

Comment: Declaring large static array types is just for the pointer types (the alternative used to be `PBla = ^TBla; TBla = array[0..0] of X;` and you use `PBla` as the parameter type). This is a good thing if the other side wants to access the elements. But I forgot that the other side is C (or C++), and that has no problems accessing arrays through a pointer.